# Pack C# project to dll or another library

Tags: c#, package

I have a C# project with many classes. Is it possible to pack this project(Console application) into library(maybe dll or anything else) and invoke all functions of a definite class from other programming languages?

EDIT:
Here is the code:

`using System;
using System.Text;`

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public int aplusb(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

```
    public void hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Helo world");
    }
}
```

}

And the hierarchy in project folder:
- Properties
- References
- bin
-- Debug
--- Test.dll
--- Test.exe
--- Test.pdb
--- Test.vshost.exe
--- Test.vshost.exe.manifest
- obj
-- x86
---Debug
----TempPE
----- DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
----- Test.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
----- Test.dll
----- Test.pdb
----- ResolveAssemblyReference.cache
- Program.cs

I checked both Test.dll from bin and obj. They are empty

Comment: doesn't matter, maybe C# again, but from other projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you build the project you get the dll in the corresponding bin folder.

You can use this dll in other project by adding reference to this dll. After that you can use its methods.

Comment: but it's empty, I check it with Dll viewer and it shows nothing

Comment: I mean dll DOES exist, but it's empty

Comment: do you added any function in your class library.

Comment: can you please check with *.net reflector*

Comment: I created a test class with two public methods(no main method), didn't compile it, because it's impossible if you choose class library. checked dll - it's empty

Comment: compile the whole solution. then only we get the dll with that methods

Comment: what do you mean by saying "compile the whole solution". It is not being compiled when in class library mode. I built the solution, no result. I set Console applicatoin, compile it, set Class library, build again, no result - still empty dll

Comment: i think you are using visual studio. In VS goto SolutionExplorer right click the class library and click build . It will build ur class library.

Comment: yeap, I built it many times, but there's no result. dll is empty. I don't know why.

Comment: Usually by building it will create the dlls. is there any way to get your project files?

Comment: Are you using name spaces correctly in all your classes? I suspect this might affect the resulting library. Also, check (under "build"?) in the settings view for the project, if there are any settings specifying things to include or exclude from the build.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right. Dll explorer just didn't show it, but I can use the library. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Project Properties -> Application -> Output Type: Class Library

Comment: DLL is in your project's bin or release folder. If it looks empty is because your classes are defined as private or internal. You should change the names you need to see outside your dll to public.

Comment: no, they are public, inside the Program class I created 2 public methods just for testing, I deleted main method.

Comment: I suggest that you start a new project, using the class library project template, and copy your code there in a public class.

Comment: I don't need a new project and copying. This one was created just for testing. I have a big project which I wanna convert into a dll, that's why I'm testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a class library project. Just keep in mind you are creating a dll with managed code, if you want to use it in for example c++ you have to do [some extra stuff.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736)

Comment: I know that it's possible to create class library project. The question is where it's possible or not to create a library from a project(Console application)?

Comment: @Sergey You could, but you'd have to create an extra project with Class Library as its output type, and reference the same code as the console application.

Answer (score 0):

Class libraries you create with .NET (which end up being DLLs) are only usable from within other .NET applications or libraries, or - if you choose to enable it - from COM.

As far as I know, it's not possible to create a DLL with C# whose methods you can then call from an unmanaged application (C, C++, etc.). There are no so called 'exported methods', which is why DLL viewer shows it to be empty. Check again using .NET Reflector or a similar decompiler, and you'll see the methods show up.