# Type or namespace could not be found, but it's there

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, namespaces, scope

I created a dll which contains a public class with public methods.

I added that dll as a reference in a new project and i'm trying to create a new object from the dll's class

```
using myDll;

namespace foo
{
    class bar
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myDll.myClass test = new myDll.myClass();
            test.myVoidMethod();
            [...]
```

but when i try to use `test` visual studio says that

```
The type or namespace name 'test' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is that a scope problem?

mydll code (excerpt):

```
using System;

namespace myDll
{

    public class myClass
    {
       public static void myVoidMethod()
       {
           Console.Write("Hello");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer to this question can be found on this post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715612/reference-added-but-namespace-is-not-recognized

Comment: Make sure there is no `test` class or namespace - that very well could cause confusion (but probably not the case of the error). Side note: usually C# classes/methods named with upper case...

Comment: @Thomas: i added the dll code

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: there's no conflicting namespaces/classes/whatever... (above code is just an example of my situation)

Comment: Is the dll located in a different project?

Comment: @sockfd as i wrote in the second line, yes i did

Comment: @Doc hope that problems is related to a Visual Studio issue.

Comment: The usefull information would be all the code of class `bar` with the line and column where you have your error.

Comment: that code can't be right - you're calling a static method on an instance variable.

Comment: @Doc - in case of syntax errors like this you either need to post real code that causes the problem OR create sample that reproduces the problem. Currently (as LewisT pointed out) code sample makes no sense and as result there are plenty of similar questions on SO already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :**  you should not use instance reference variable to accee the `static` methods.

**Solution :** You should call `static` methods using their `classname`

Try This:

```
myDll.myClass.myVoidMethod();
```

**EDIT:**  From Your comments `but i want to create a new object`

Your error is not coming from first line where you are creating the instance variable , its from second statement while calling `static` method using instance variable.

You are stillbe able to create an intance for your class

Try This:

```
myDll.myClass test = new myDll.myClass(); //it works
myDll.myClass.myVoidMethod();
```

Comment: Your error is not at first line while creating the instance variable , its in second statement while calling static method. try this alone `myDll.myClass test = new myDll.myClass();` it works

Comment: +1. @Doc - can you please explain how creation of new object is related to calling static method?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi the static keyword was the problem, you're right

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the property `Build Action` on `Compile` of the source file of your class?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your project isn't set up to use the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. (as the link below tells us): [Namespace not recognized (even though it is there)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228992/namespace-not-recognized-even-though-it-is-there). This may be very helpful for you.

Comment: Have you tried so far to look on another posts here on StackOverflow?

Comment: i always search before asking something... -.-